# Find Triangle Triplets from a list of given numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, computational-geometry, c++14

> If a triplet of segments A, B and C are triangle triplets if and only
> if
>
> - A + B > C
> - A + C > B
> - B + C > A

Is there a better implementation for this problem?

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

void findTriangleTriplets( std::vector<int>& vec_input, std::vector<std::vector<int>>& triplets)
{
    int size =  vec_input.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < size; ++j)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < size; ++k)
            {
                if( ( ( vec_input.at( i ) + vec_input.at( j ) ) > vec_input.at( k ) ) &&
                    ( ( vec_input.at( i ) + vec_input.at( k ) ) > vec_input.at( j ) ) &&
                    ( ( vec_input.at( j ) + vec_input.at( k ) ) > vec_input.at( i ) ) )
                {               
                    std::vector<int> temp;
                    temp.emplace_back( vec_input.at( i ) );
                    temp.emplace_back( vec_input.at( j ) ); 
                    temp.emplace_back( vec_input.at( k ) );
                    triplets.emplace_back( temp );
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>  triplets;
    std::vector<int> vec_input { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
   
    findTriangleTriplets( vec_input,  triplets);
    for ( auto &x : triplets)
    {
        std::cout<<x.at(0)<<" "<<x.at(1)<<" "<<x.at(2)<<"\n";
    }         

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to comment on after copying and pasting into my IDE, the following line gives a warning:

> ```
> int size = vec_input.size();
> ```
>
> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int'

Apparently, the `size()` method of Vector returns an `unsigned long`, and we should use this type for our `size`, rather than `int`.

```
unsigned long size = input.size();
```

---

Functions that return `void` but accept (and modify) an argument passed by reference are always a warning sign for me.  Here, I don't think there's a particularly good reason to do so.

Here, I can't see any good reason to be doing so.  We create and return a vector within the function, and only accept the input argument.

---

Another problem I see: the result we're giving the caller is a vector of vectors, and the inner vectors are supposed to always have exactly 3 values in it.  Why don't we create a struct to represent the triplets?

```
struct Triplet {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Now we can return a vector of these.

---

I would also abstract that complex conditional into its own function.

```
bool isTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
    return ((a + b) > c) && ((a + c) > b) && ((b + c) > a);
}
```

---

Now, putting all that together, without changing the algorithm or any of the logic, the code looks like this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

struct Triplet {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

bool isTriplet(int a, int b, int c) {
    return ((a + b) > c) && ((a + c) > b) && ((b + c) > a);
}

std::vector<Triplet> findTriangleTriplets(std::vector<int> input) {
    std::vector<Triplet> triplets;
    unsigned long size = input.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;++i) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<size;++j) {
            for(int k=0;k<size;++k) {
                int a = input.at(i);
                int b = input.at(j);
                int c = input.at(k);

                if(isTriplet(a, b, c)) {
                    Triplet t = Triplet{a,b,c};
                    triplets.emplace_back(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return triplets;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Triplet> triplets;
    std::vector<int> vec_input { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    triplets = findTriangleTriplets(vec_input);
    for ( auto &x : triplets)
    {
        std::cout<<x.a<<" "<<x.b<<" "<<x.c<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, `vector<T>::size()` returns `vector<T>::size_type`, which is more likely a typedef to `std::size_t` than to `unsigned long`. However, in this case, `auto` would have been the ideal usage: `auto size = vec_input.size();`. Let the compiler figure that out. Good review, nevertheless.

Comment: @glampert Yeah, I'm not C++ expert.  My IDE was warning me that it was `unsigned long`, so that's what I used.  `auto` does seem like it would be good indeed (I really didn't know what it did, but I think I got it now...)  `size_t` is probably typedef'd to `unsigned long`?

Comment: This warning is present in g++, clang was not showing this warning

Comment: Yep, `size_t` is usually uint or ulong. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4849646/1198654

Comment: @Steephen, indeed `clang` seems to miss this even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`. If you try compiling with the `-Weverything` flag, you'll see that `clang` does this value narrowing diagnostic under the `-Wshorten-64-to-32` flag.

Comment: I'd go one step further, and make `isTriplet` a member of `Triplet` structure. Among other things, it makes obvious that `isTriplet` is wrong name, and should be `isTriangle`.

Comment: In the answer code, usage of passing vector<int> as value  for function findTriangleTriplets() should be corrected as passing by reference